# How to compute the average of numpy files in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of numpy files in one folder, each file has a shape (8000,)
I want to compute the average of those numpy files:

```
Power_Result_File_Path='E:\\test.npy'
Traces =r'E:\\Test'
sum_trace=0
os.chdir(Traces)
Traces_Without_Sort=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
Traces_Sorted=sorted((Traces_Without_Sort),key=os.path.getmtime)  
tempMeans = np.zeros(8000)
print (tempMeans.shape)
print (tempMeans)
tempMeans=np.average(Traces_Sorted,0)
print (tempMeans)
np.save(Power_Result_File_Path, tempMeans)
```

But I have this error:

```
    ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)

TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

So that I can't resolve this problem, I would be very grateful if you could help me please.

Comment: To locate the row with error, try to comment all rows and uncomment them step-by-step from the last. I suppose the error is in third from the end row.

Comment: What is `Traces_Sorted`?  It looks like a list of file names.  `np.average` works on a numeric array.  You'll have to load the file contents first.